# How to center a div specifically my container in this situation?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

SO this is my code and I have been trying to center my Div ( **CONTAINER**) but It sticks to the left side every time, i have tried using (align-content, and used flex on the body, but it doesn't solve the problem)

I used ( margin: 0 auto;) on the container and it does the trick but the container is still sticking to top

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@400;700&display=swap");

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "karla", sans-serif;
  background: lightblue;
}
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  background: white;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title name="second_project">Project</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta lang="en">
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
    </head>
    

    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="main">
                <h1 class="main_heading mainco">Join out community</h1>
                <h2 class="sub_heading">30-day, hassle-free money back guarantee</h2>
                <p class="main_content">Gain access to our full library of tutorials along with expert code reviews. Perfect for any developers who are serious about honing their skills</p>
            </div>

            <main>
                
                 <section>
                    <div class="split">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Monthly Subscription</h1>
                            <span>$29<span>per month</span></span>
                            <h1>Full access for less than $1 a day</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button>Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        
                </section>
                <section>
                    <div class="split">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Why us</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul class="reasons">
                                <li class="items">Tutorials by industry experts.</li>
                                <li class="items">Peer & expert code review</li>
                                <li class="items">Coding exercises</li>
                                <li class="items">Access to our GitHub repos</li>
                                <li class="items">Community forum</li>
                                <li class="items">FlashCard decks</li>
                                <li class="items">New videos every week</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                
               
            </main>   
           
        </header>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: margin:0 auto it works

Comment: Your `body` will only be as tall as the sum of its child elements, and in the case you have your `container` set to 800px tall - and it's the only element. That's why it's "sticking" to the top. You also have your flex alignment props on your container, when they should be on the body.

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to use flex, the flex css needs to be on the parent of the element you want to center like this:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@400;700&display=swap");
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "karla", sans-serif;
  background: lightblue;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title name="second_project">Project</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta lang="en">
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
</head>


<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div class="main">
        <h1 class="main_heading mainco">Join out community</h1>
        <h2 class="sub_heading">30-day, hassle-free money back guarantee</h2>
        <p class="main_content">Gain access to our full library of tutorials along with expert code reviews. Perfect for any developers who are serious about honing their skills</p>
      </div>

      <main>

        <section>
          <div class="split">
            <div>
              <h1>Monthly Subscription</h1>
              <span>$29<span>per month</span></span>
              <h1>Full access for less than $1 a day</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button>Sign Up</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </section>
        <section>
          <div class="split">
            <div>
              <h1>Why us</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <ul class="reasons">
                <li class="items">Tutorials by industry experts.</li>
                <li class="items">Peer & expert code review</li>
                <li class="items">Coding exercises</li>
                <li class="items">Access to our GitHub repos</li>
                <li class="items">Community forum</li>
                <li class="items">FlashCard decks</li>
                <li class="items">New videos every week</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>


      </main>

    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `flex-direction: row` is the default value for that property. In this case it is redundant. However this will cause other issues if more elements are present as you prevent the normal block level behavior. As such `flex-direction: column` + `align-items: center` would be more appropiate. Nontheless it is completely over the top as you dont need flexbox at all. just use `margin: 0 auto` to center block level elements.

Comment: Thanks @tacoshy. You are correct as usual. I appreciate the feedback. I did include the disclaimer "And if you want to use flex...".

Comment: The main issue I got with the solution is `body { flex-direction: row; }` for reasons explained above. Please at least fix that and I will revoke the down-vote

Comment: @tacoshy - done. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rob Moll it is still not solving any problems that  I am having, my code has been already doing this, what I want is to center the container both horizontally and vertically but it is keep sticking to the top

Comment: @Alucard of course it is "sticking" to the top. Look at my comment on your question. Your `container` is the only child element, therefore the `body` is only as tall as your `container`.

Answer (score 1):

just add `margin: 0 auto;` to `.container`. It works fine.

```
.container {   
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@400;700&display=swap");
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "karla", sans-serif;
  background: lightblue;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="main">
      <h1 class="main_heading mainco">Join out community</h1>
      <h2 class="sub_heading">30-day, hassle-free money back guarantee</h2>
      <p class="main_content">Gain access to our full library of tutorials along with expert code reviews. Perfect for any developers who are serious about honing their skills</p>
    </div>

    <main>

      <section>
        <div class="split">
          <div>
            <h1>Monthly Subscription</h1>
            <span>$29<span>per month</span></span>
            <h1>Full access for less than $1 a day</h1>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button>Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </section>
      <section>
        <div class="split">
          <div>
            <h1>Why us</h1>
          </div>
          <div>
            <ul class="reasons">
              <li class="items">Tutorials by industry experts.</li>
              <li class="items">Peer & expert code review</li>
              <li class="items">Coding exercises</li>
              <li class="items">Access to our GitHub repos</li>
              <li class="items">Community forum</li>
              <li class="items">FlashCard decks</li>
              <li class="items">New videos every week</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>


    </main>

  </header>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

A common and very easy option would be to work with `margin: 0 auto;` in your container style.

Like that:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "karla", sans-serif;
  background: lightblue;
}
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title name="second_project">Project</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta lang="en">
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
    </head>
    

    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="main">
                <h1 class="main_heading mainco">Join out community</h1>
                <h2 class="sub_heading">30-day, hassle-free money back guarantee</h2>
                <p class="main_content">Gain access to our full library of tutorials along with expert code reviews. Perfect for any developers who are serious about honing their skills</p>
            </div>

            <main>
                
                 <section>
                    <div class="split">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Monthly Subscription</h1>
                            <span>$29<span>per month</span></span>
                            <h1>Full access for less than $1 a day</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button>Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        
                </section>
                <section>
                    <div class="split">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Why us</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul class="reasons">
                                <li class="items">Tutorials by industry experts.</li>
                                <li class="items">Peer & expert code review</li>
                                <li class="items">Coding exercises</li>
                                <li class="items">Access to our GitHub repos</li>
                                <li class="items">Community forum</li>
                                <li class="items">FlashCard decks</li>
                                <li class="items">New videos every week</li>
                      

      </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                
               
            </main>   
           
        </header>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should use `margin: 0 auto` other wise you can get have unintend behavior with the top and bottom margin.

Comment: @tacoshy thx for your good comment. you are right. ... done.

Answer (score -1):

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@400;700&display=swap");

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "karla", sans-serif;
  background: lightblue;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container header {
  width: 300px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title name="second_project">Project</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta lang="en">
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
    </head>
    

    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="main">
                <h1 class="main_heading mainco">Join out community</h1>
                <h2 class="sub_heading">30-day, hassle-free money back guarantee</h2>
                <p class="main_content">Gain access to our full library of tutorials along with expert code reviews. Perfect for any developers who are serious about honing their skills</p>
            </div>

            <main>
                
                 <section>
                    <div class="split">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Monthly Subscription</h1>
                            <span>$29<span>per month</span></span>
                            <h1>Full access for less than $1 a day</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button>Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        
                </section>
                <section>
                    <div class="split">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Why us</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul class="reasons">
                                <li class="items">Tutorials by industry experts.</li>
                                <li class="items">Peer & expert code review</li>
                                <li class="items">Coding exercises</li>
                                <li class="items">Access to our GitHub repos</li>
                                <li class="items">Community forum</li>
                                <li class="items">FlashCard decks</li>
                                <li class="items">New videos every week</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                
               
            </main>   
           
        </header>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```